# Find the pattern inside the file name in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have the database with the specific names. I need to iterate the database records and find the records which have the appropriate pattern.
For example:
Pattern with wildcard:
`abc.*.cde`
File name:
`abc.123.cde`

How can I check that the name "abc.123.cde" is a part of the pattern "abc.*.cde" ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems I have to use the fnmatch module:

```
fnmatch.fnmatch(files, 'abc.*.cde')
```

Will return me the files according to the pattern.